# Is it possible to write custom prop-type validator for conditionally required array of objects without losing object validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am using prop-types in a react component. The component has a prop `data` which should be an array of objects like this: `[{value: 'some string', id: 123}]`. I want to add a custom prop-type function  that makes `data` required if `props.useCustomSuggestions` is `false`. I tried something like this:

```
data: (props) => {
  if (!props.useCustomSuggestions && !props.data) {
    return new Error('Data must be provided to use default suggestions');
  } else if (props.data && typeof props.data !== 'object') {
    return new Error(
      'Data must be an array',
    );
  }
};
```

I believe this works to validate that the array is required when `props.useCustomSuggestions` is `false`, but it doesn't check wether the objects in `data` are formatted correctly. Is there another way to write this that validates the array is composed of objects with properties `value` of type string and `id` of type number?

I thought the [customArrayProp](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) documentation in react might be the solution, but it doesn't pass the entire props object so I lose the ability to make `data` conditionally required on the value of `useCustomSuggestions`.

Comment: just to think about: probably it makes sense to extract component for list item and check shape prop type inside of it. More readable -> better maintainable.

Comment: @skyboyer I've been trying to think of a good way to do that. The component in question is a suggestion dropdown attached to a text input. If `useCustomSuggestions` is false, then we handle all the filtering logic for their data to display the most relevant suggestions/return the filtered data for them. If it's true, they handle all the filtering on their end using their own rules, and then just pass the suggestions to be displayed back to us. The only option I could think of to eliminate the conditional props is to make those options two totally different components.

Comment: Which I can't decide if is a good solution because visually they'd be exactly the same.

Comment: without more details(especially about what does it mean "handling all the filtering on their end") it's too generic question to have the only solution. but for both cases and props structure, and UI look are the same, right? just different filtering rules are applied, am I correct?

Comment: Correct, the UI is the same, but the filtering would be different. The primary use case for this is if the data is coming from a paginated API so the user needs to call the API to get the correct suggestions. I recognize this is probably getting out of scope for the original question, so may need to be a new question all together. If I post one I'll link it in the comments here. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special way to [call `propTypes` check directly](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/README.md#difference-from-reactproptypes-dont-call-validator-functions) for reusing their check logic: `PropTypes.checkPropTypes()`

```
data: (props, propName, componentName) => {
  if (props.useCustomSuggestion) {  // data should be validated but is optional
    PropTypes.checkPropTypes({ 
        [propName]: PropTypes.arrayOf(
          PropTypes.shape({
            value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            id: PropTypes.number.isRequired
         }) 
        ) 
      }, 
      props, 
      propName, 
      componentName
    );
  } else { // data is required
    PropTypes.checkPropTypes({ 
        [propName]: PropTypes.arrayOf(
          PropTypes.shape({
            value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            id: PropTypes.number.isRequired
         }) 
        ).isRequired
      }, 
      props, 
      propName, 
      componentName
    );
  }
}
```

PS for unknown reason codesandbox sometimes run `propTypes` check and sometimes silently skipped that, so I'm not 100% my code sample works. But I've checked approach with `string`/`number` - just when I was trying to adopt that to `arrayOf`/`shape` it started to go weird.

Probably you will be able to move common part(`shape`'s internal) to interm variable to reduce code duplication, but as I said was unable to ensure that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick, if anyone has a more concise answer, or feedback on the below code please still comment or post your own answer.

```
data: (props) => {
  if (!props.useCustomSuggestions && !props.data) {
    return new Error('Data must be provided to use default suggestions');
  } else if (props.data && !Array.isArray(props.suggestions)) {
    return new Error('Data must be an array');
  } else if (props.data.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < props.data.length; i += 1) {
      if (!props.data[i].value || !props.data[i].id) {
        return new Error(
          'Objects in data must include properties "value" and "id"',
        );
      } else if (
        typeof props.data[i].value !== 'string' ||
        typeof props.data[i].id !== 'number'
      ) {
        return new Error(
          'Objects in data array must have property "value" of type string, and "id" of type number',
        );
      }
    }
  }
},
```